How to handle mouse click or mouse down over ErrorProvider icon in WinForms
I would like to display an error provider icon over a button at certain times, like this:

However, I also don't want the icon to obscure/prevent the button click if the user happens to click on that when intending to click on the button, perhaps because the error message on hover says something like "click here to fix".
ErrorProvider has no events (well it has one irrelevant one).  I tried using the methodology described in this post, but the problem is that no pre-filter message even occurs when I click on the error icon.  Here's my sample code:
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        errorProvider1.SetIconPadding(button1, -27);
        errorProvider1.SetError(button1, "error");
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        var ctrl = Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
        var msg = m.Msg;

        // the values in the "ignore" list below are all movement/paint events
        if (ctrl is Button b && (!(new[] { 15, 512, 675, 280, 673 }.Any((v) => msg == v))))
        {
            // only gets here when un-obscured button surface is clicked.
        }

        // this only ever prints form and button
        if (ctrl != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"{ctrl.GetType().Name}"); 

        return false;
    }
}

Is there any way to do this?

You wish to display an error icon "at certain times". At which times exactly? What are the events who make the error condition change? Those might not be related to the button itself, but e.g., by a text entered in a TextBox or a selection made in a ComboBox or ListBox. Probably you can simply change the icon state in a normal event handler of one of these controls. Or if you are using data binding you can implement IDataErrorInfo and the ErrorProvider hide or show the icon automatically.

If PrefilterMessage is called, then you have a message. Not directed to a Control, the ErrorProvidier is not one and it uses a HashTable of NativeWindow objects (not of the ControlNativeWindow derived Type, what FromHandle() tests) to handle the drawing Regions used for the Icons. So, don't use Control.FromHandle

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I don't need to hide the icon.  The condition that makes it appear there is irrelevant.  I just want to be able to click it and have it act as if I clicked the button underneath it.

Clicking the button (or the icon) won't fix the issue/make the icon disappear.  It's just an indication that there's a problem, and clicking the button opens a view where the problem can be fixed (or not...)

@rory.ap: "[...]clicking the button opens a view where the problem can be fixed" - though in my answer I make the icon disappear when it's clicked, it's handled in the button click as well, ie. clicking the icon causes a regular button click where you can display your new view. If you don't even need that the tooltip is shown only when you hover the icon area as if it was an error provider (instead, it works for the whole button area), see the update at the bottom. I hope it provides some usable ideas for your case.

Why not simply add an image to the button in the error case then? You can specify TextImageRelation to be TextBeforeImage to make it look like above.

As you want to display the error icon inside the button, you can easily fake the ErrorProvider by drawing the icon manually and using a ToolTip explicitly:
public partial class FakeErrorProvider : Form
{
    private static Icon _errorIcon = new ErrorProvider().Icon;
    private static int _errorIconPadding = 4;

    private ToolTip _toolTip;
    private bool _hasError;

    public FakeErrorProvider()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _toolTip = new ToolTip();
        button1.Click += Button1_Click;
        button1.Paint += Button1_Paint;
        button1.MouseMove += Button1_MouseMove;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // fixing the error only when the error icon is clicked
        if (!_hasError || GetErrorRectangle(button1).Contains(button1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
            _hasError = !_hasError;
        button1.Invalidate();
        if (!_hasError)
            _toolTip.SetToolTip(button1, String.Empty);
    }

    private void Button1_Paint(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // showing the error icon
        if (_hasError)
            e.Graphics.DrawIcon(_errorIcon, GetErrorRectangle(button1));
    }

    private void Button1_MouseMove(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // displaying the error tooltip only when the cursor is above the error icon
        bool isVisible = _toolTip.GetToolTip(button1).Length > 0;
        if (_hasError && !isVisible && GetErrorRectangle(button1).Contains(e.Location))
            _toolTip.SetToolTip(button1, "click here to fix");
        else if (isVisible && (!_hasError || !GetErrorRectangle(button1).Contains(e.Location)))
            _toolTip.SetToolTip(button1, String.Empty);
    }

    private Rectangle GetErrorRectangle(Button button)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, _errorIcon.Size);
        rect.Offset(button.Width - rect.Width - _errorIconPadding, button.Height / 2 - rect.Height / 2);
        return rect;
    }
}

And the result:


Edit:
If clicking any part of the button should fix the issue, the solution is even simpler because you don't need to bother with the icon area at all and the tooltip can be displayed when you hover any part of the button just like a normal tooltip.
Just set button1.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.TextBeforeImage, and then simply adjust button1.Image along with the tooltip.
